# How to fix this header for a streaming?

Tags: php, header, stream

I need to stream a media file from another server through this php file.

```
<?php
$out = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Content-type: audio/mpeg\r\n", 
  )
);

$stream = stream_context_create($out);

$end = fopen('http://example.com/audio.mp3', 'r', false, $stream);
fpassthru($end);
readfile($end);
?>
```

But the header doesn't work.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Is content-length also needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the header in the wrong direction. What you have done is informed the source server that you will be sending it some `audio/mpeg` in a GET request - which is invalid anyway, GET requests don't have content. What you actually need to do is send it to the client who will be receiving the content.

You shouldn't need the stream context for this task - try this code:

```
<?php

  // Try and open the remote stream
  if (!$stream = fopen('http://example.com/audio.mp3', 'r')) {
    // If opening failed, inform the client we have no content
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit('Unable to open remote stream');
  }

  // It's probably an idea to remove the execution time limit - on Windows hosts
  // this could result in the audio stream cutting off mid-flow
  set_time_limit(0);

  // Inform the client we will be sending it some MPEG audio
  header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');

  // Send the data
  fpassthru($stream);
```

Comment: Nice solution! But in iOS (5.0.1) the streaming is a bit slow even with a mp3 128kbps. Any ideas of why? PD: I'm streaming from a faster VPS.

Comment: How are you testing this? Over a mobile network or WiFi? Keep in mind that you are limited by the slowest link in the chain of transmission between the client and the remote server. So if the client's internet connection is not capable of 128kbps + packet overhead, it won't work. Similarly if your server runs into a bandwidth problem it will also not work, same goes for the original source server. Your server will need 128k + packet overhead symmetric for each concurrent stream, as you are simultaneously downloading the data from the source server and uploading it to the client.

Comment: This is one major reason why realtime media streaming protocols generally use UDP. This is less viable over wireless connections due to their inherently lossy nature, but it drastically reduces overhead and should be implemented wherever possible. UDP streams are more susceptible to small errors due to lost packets out-of-order arrivals, but TCP streams will potentially result in retransmissions and this will add to the required bandwidth, and the wait time for the continuation of the data stream.

Answer (score 0):

After fopen, add

```
header('content-type: audio/mpeg');
or
header('content-type: application/octet-stream');
```

Comment: The second example would usually force the browser to download instead.